# Clementine doesn't seem to have permissions to orginize files in mounted drive

Tags: permissions, music, clementine

When I try to add a folder on a mounted HDD, clementine says permission denied. When I try to go to /mnt that's when the message appears. The HDD auto mounts at startup with pretty much default options(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyhF7.png).

I tried searching the internet but can't find anything.

Other snaps like Deja dup can access the drive. and permissions to the music folder are set exactly the same as the home directory music folder.

**Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS** 
**Clementine snap - Version 1.4.0rc1-465-gb69dd2d90**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clementine snap mentions the `removable-media` interface, which is used to enable applications to see mounted media like this.

Try `snap connect clementine:removable-media`.

Comment: Oh, yes! That finally did it. Thank you so much.